# How can I use prettier to *only* prettify code inside Markdown files?

Tags: markdown, prettier

I have a bunch of Markdown files with code examples that use wildly different styles - a bit like StackOverflow itself!

I've done some research and found that [Prettier added markdown support](https://prettier.io/blog/2017/11/07/1.8.0.html#markdown-support) including the ability to format code inside code blocks!

By default [Prettier doesn't change Markdown prose](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#prose-wrap) which is also great. I'm running `prose-wrap` anyway below just to be explicit.

However when I run:

```
npx prettier --prose-wrap=preserve -w developers
```

I see many thousands of small changes like:

```
fruit: banana
something:
- I am a bullet point
```

Being changed to:

```
fruit: banana
something:
  - I am a bullet point
```

**How can I make prettier just format the code blocks, and not change the outer Markdown content?**